# Moving multiple bones with blender python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a Blender Python script that moves three bones in an armature based on columns in a CSV file. I’ve gotten it to consistently move one bone, but when I try to do more than that one, the script will only move one of the bones. It does seem to create keyframes for the rest.

The variables are as follows:

`Cnt` = a count variable

`Fcnt` = Frame count, this is the current frame, and has other uses earlier in the code

`Bone_1`, `Bone_2`, and `Bone_3` : the bones in the armature

`col1`, `col2`, and `col3`: columns in the CSV file that correspond to the locations for `Bone_1`, `Bone_2`, and `Bone_3`.

Additional context:
At this point, the armature is already selected and blender enters pose mode.

Code begins:

```
for row in col1:
     bpy.context.scene.frame_current = Fcnt


     C1 = col1[CnT]
     C2 = col2[CnT]
     C3 = col3[CnT]


     # Bone_1:

     # Deselect All:
     bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')

     # Select bone to move:
     Bone_1.select= True

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     # Move Bone:
     bpy.context.active_pose_bone.location[1] = C1

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     # Bone_2
        
     # Deselect All:
     bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')

     # Select bone to move:
     Bone_2.select= True

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     # Move Bone:
     bpy.context.active_pose_bone.location[1] = C2

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     # Bone_3:
        
     # Deselect All:
     bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')

     # Select bone to move:
     Bone_3.select= True

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     # Move Bone:
     bpy.context.active_pose_bone.location[1] = C3

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

     bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')    

     CnT += 1
     Fcnt += 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bone you want to move is the active bone, not the selected bone.

```
# Move Bone:
bpy.context.active_pose_bone.location[1] = Cn
```

Therefore, you need to use

```
# Set active bone to move:
bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = Bone_n
```

instead of

```
# Select bone to move:
Bone_n.select= True
```

Then, it is better to delete the first Add Keyframe.

```
# Add Keyframe:
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")
```

---

```
     # Bone_1:

     # Deselect All:
     bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')

     # Set active bone to move:
     bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = Bone_1

     # Move Bone:
     bpy.context.active_pose_bone.location[1] = C1

     # Add Keyframe:
     bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with a different solution but you definitely put me on the right track. I'd like to understand your solution though as I'm still new at this and I couldn't get it to work exactly how you suggested. 

In my solution, I sidestepped selecting the bones and changed their locations like this:

 Bone_1.location[1] = C1
 Bone_2.location[1] = C2
 Bone_3.location[1] = C3

Then selected all and added the keyframe. 

In the bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = Bone_1, do I need to add the name of the Armature in brackets or something? I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: @Bobby J. Bee
 As long as *type(Bone_1)* is *<class 'bpy_types.Bone'>*, you don't need to add anything to that snippet. Note that the *keyframe_insert_by_name* function inserts keyframes into the active bone as well as the selected bones.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You've been a huge help!